# Как при абсолютном позиционировании svg-картинку поставит по центру?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

```css
path
 stroke: #fff
 fill: #fff
 stroke-dasharray: 2780
 opacity: 2
 transform: scale(.5)
 animation: animate  cubic-bezier(.65,.94,.74,.25) 6s 

.piz
 position: absolute
 top: 30%
 left: 17%
```

```html
<div class="map">

 <svg  class="piz" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="419" width="958" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent">
  <path>
        4-5.034-1.012-1.385-2.31-1.719-5.5-1.415-5.819.555-5.53-1.828.328-2.707 3.363-.504 5.133-.261 7 .962 2.29 1.5 2.498 2.251 2.498 8.997 0 6.52.228 7.42 2 7.883 1.1.288 2 1.016 2 1.617 0 1.39-5.259 1.435-6.637.056-.716-.716-1.881-.716-3.765 0-3.82 1.452-6.198 1.294-8.027-.534zM478.8 52.8c1.67-1.67 1.5-4.748-.302-5.44-.826-.317-2.646-.289-4.043.061-4.793 1.203-4.537 6.578.314 6.578 1.557 0 3.371-.54 4.031-1.2zm26.4 3c-.66-.66-1.2-2.91-1.2-5V47h-9v4.5c0 3.833-.296 4.5-2 4.5-1.843 0-2-.667-2-8.5 0-6.89-.284-8.5-1.5-8.5-.825 0-1.5-.675-1.5-1.5 0-1.048 1.056-1.5 3.5-1.5 3.417 0 3.5.095 3.5 4v4h9v-4c0-3.334.333-4 2-4 1.852 0 2 .666 2 9 0 7.333.278 9 1.5 9 .825 0 1.5.675 1.5 1.5 0 1.814-4.075 2.025-5.8.3zm25 0c-.66-.66-1.2-2.91-1.2-5V47h-9v4.5c0 3.833-.296 4.5-2 4.5-1.843 0-2-.667-2-8.5 0-6.89-.284-8.5-1.5-8.5-.825 0-1.5-.675-1.5-1.5 0-1.048 1.056-1.5 3.5-1.5 3.417 0 3.5.095 3.5 4v4h9v-4c0-3.334.333-4 2-4 1.852 0 2 .666 2 9 0 7.333.278 9 1.5 9 .825 0 1.5.675 1.5 1.5 0 1.814-4.075 2.025-5.8.3zm12.82-.084c-3.521-1.782-5.174-5.493-4.68-10.506.51-5.165 2.803-7.959 7.212-8.786 4.846-.909 8.696 1.335 10.207 5.947 3.148 9.607-4.433 17.547-12.74 13.345zm8.108-3.37c.754-.91 1.372-3.54 1.372-5.846 0-4.866-1.779-7.5-5.066-7.5-4.432 0-7.12 7.982-4.399 13.066 1.292 2.415 6.18 2.584 8.093.28zm14.723 3.525c-3.4-1.246-5.263-5.76-4.556-11.037.75-5.59 3.621-8.288 8.817-8.288 4.982 0 7.888 2.971 7.888 8.065V48h-6.5c-6.72 0-7.374.497-5.427 4.135.895 1.674 1.927 1.96 6.25 1.73 5.258-.28 6.743 1.085 2.486 2.284-3.274.922-5.905.84-8.958-.279zM575 44.565c0-.239-.439-1.589-.975-3-1.135-2.986-4.953-3.494-7.454-.993C563.546 43.597 564.631 45 570 45c2.75 0 5-.196 5-.435z" fill="transparent"/>
   </svg>
```

здравствуйте у меня есть код svg-картинки как сделать чтобы она при любых разрешениях всегда стояла по центру ?

Comment: ваш код в студию

Comment: сейчас, уже бегуууууу

Comment: вставил яяяяяяяяяя

Comment: Эта ваша `<!-- портянка из непонятных цифр -->` - это изображение. пожалуйста вставьте и его

Comment: вставил яяяяяяя

Comment: Я не знаю, что это за код такой, потому что `path` указан не верно, ваш HTML не полный, в sass пропущена `.` перед `path`

Comment: . означает в sass класс, а это не класс, а тег,

Comment: точно, простите, недоглядел, не помню просто кто вообще в path задает стили

Comment: между path я вставил часть когда потому что весь код вставлять, то получится очень большой и в чем смысл это видеть не знаю

Comment: теперь знаете кто :))

Comment: ок спасибо, если надо вставлю весь код

Comment: главное, что бы он работал

Comment: Подскажите как можно уменьшать svg-картинку, я использую transform: scale (.4), а как еще можно ?

Comment: чем вас не устраивает `transform: scale (.4)` ?

Comment: изменил ответ) так точнее будет

Comment: Другие способы хотел узнать кроме transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте поступим вот как - Я не понимаю, что должен делать ваш код, где он расположен, и какова структура файла. Я взял случайный `svg` (это не на что не влияет) - я думаю такой результат вы хотели.

```css
.map{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
svg{
 position: absolute;
 transform: scale(.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
 <svg class="svg" width="150" height="130">
    <symbol id="s-crown">
        <path d="M 10,110 L 10,10 L 40,50 L 70,10 L 100,50 L 130,10 L 130,110 z"
          fill="gold" stroke="orange" stroke-width="5"/>
    </symbol>

  <use xlink:href="#s-crown" x="5" y="7"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Помогло вам или нет?